# POST request to Firebase, not working like intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

So my problem is next... It wont send POST request when I put the http address like this, dynamically, even thou it is ordinary email in array, eg. [ 'test@test.com' ]. If i put orders/order1.json it sends post request like it should... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

```
 axios
        .post(
          `.../orders/${
            this.props.email
          }.json`,
          {
            articleName: article.name,
            articleWeight: article.weight,
            articleInfo: article.info,
            articlePrice: article.price,
            time: new Date().toLocaleString()
          }
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around the jsx expression and then combine the strings together, this should allow the expression to evaluate and send the request to the correct api endpoint.

```
axios
        .post(
          '.../orders/$' + { this.props.email } + '.json',
          {
            articleName: article.name,
            articleWeight: article.weight,
            articleInfo: article.info,
            articlePrice: article.price,
            time: new Date().toLocaleString()
          }
        )
```

Comment: Hi Mike, I am getting Error: Request failed with status code 400 what ever I try, do not know what can be the problem... after all, it is just a string in an array...

Comment: you'll most likely want to go through and remove the `.json` part of the api endpoint. REST methods (post included) typically do not go to a file, but to a path.

Comment: Also, are you handling this endpoint with a firebase cloud function? If so, could you please post the code that handles requests to the endpoint you're posting to?

Comment: I think that for firebase you need to include .json at the end for all REST methods when working with firebase, otherwise it wont work, maybe I am wrong ...  I am not really sure what exactly do you mean, I am sending this POST request to firebase real-time database. And what ever i put instead this.props.email it sends the post req but... When I log this.props.email it logs email in black letters, I think that is a string?

Comment: That email is logged users email that I got through redux to POST request. And for some reason it wont send post req if the endpoint is an  email. Now after couple of hours i did everything the same just instead users email i got uid and now it post req just fine... That may be some firebase rule that i did not know...